# Looping through a JSON File with a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Right here I have IDs stored in a .json file.

```
{"676053251413639194":{"id":"676053251413639194", "state":true}, "534510424280793100":{"id":"534510424280793100", "state:"true}}
```

I'm trying to create a for loop for the .json file, getting every id, one at a time, and banning the user with the respective ID. Here's my ready event:

```
bot.once('ready', ready => {
    var rows = [];
    let blacklist = bl;
    for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.id; i++) {
        bot.guilds.ban(rows, blacklist.id[i]);
    }
})
```

Comment: Please do not include photos of errors or code. Instead write it in text in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming `bl` is `blacklist.json` as a javascript object. You seem to be confusing arrays and objects. Arrays can be iterated over with an index, but Objects need to be accessed with a key. You might want to read up more on them.

Objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

The solution following your style of code:

```
let blacklist_keys = Object.keys(bl);
for (var i = 0; i < blacklist_keys.length; i++){
    bot.guild.ban(rows, bl[blacklist_keys[i]].id);
}
```

Since it seems like the key of the json is already the id, you could simplify the code further.

```
let blacklist_keys = Object.keys(bl);
for (var i = 0; i < blacklist_keys.length; i++){
    bot.guild.ban(rows, blacklist_keys[i]);
}
```

And simplify even further using Array's forEach (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
Object.keys(bl).forEach(id => bot.guild.ban(rows, blacklist_keys[i]));
```